# .loc method not taking column labels of a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, label

I created a data frame in pandas and tried to display 2 columns with their labels.
My code is :

```
#5.py
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd

    exam_data = {'name': ['Anastasia', 'Dima', 'Katherine', 'James', 'Emily', 'Michael', 'Matthew', 'Laura', 'Kevin', 'Jonas'],
    'score': [12.5, 9, 16.5, np.nan, 9, 20, 14.5, np.nan, 8, 19],
    'attempts': [1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1],
    'qualify': ['yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'yes', 'no', 'no', 'yes']}
    labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']

    df = pd.DataFrame(exam_data)
    print(df.loc[:,['name', 'score']])
    #print(df.loc['name', 'score'])
```

This code runs fine, but when I replace the print statement
 `print(df.loc[:,['name', 'score']])` with 
`print(df.loc['name', 'score'])` , the program is resulting in the following errors :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Vikranth Inti/PycharmProjects/Python-Basics/Pandas/Data Frame/5.py", line 29, in <module>
    print(df.loc['name', 'score'])
  File "C:\Users\Vikranth Inti\PycharmProjects\Rough-Work\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1418, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_tuple(key)
  File "C:\Users\Vikranth Inti\PycharmProjects\Rough-Work\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 805, in _getitem_tuple


    return self._getitem_lowerdim(tup)
  File "C:\Users\Vikranth Inti\PycharmProjects\Rough-Work\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 929, in _getitem_lowerdim
    section = self._getitem_axis(key, axis=i)
  File "C:\Users\Vikranth Inti\PycharmProjects\Rough-Work\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1850, in _getitem_axis
    return self._get_label(key, axis=axis)
  File "C:\Users\Vikranth Inti\PycharmProjects\Rough-Work\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 160, in _get_label
    return self.obj._xs(label, axis=axis)
  File "C:\Users\Vikranth Inti\PycharmProjects\Rough-Work\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3737, in xs
    loc = self.index.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\Vikranth Inti\PycharmProjects\Rough-Work\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\range.py", line 379, in get_loc
    return super().get_loc(key, method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
  File "C:\Users\Vikranth Inti\PycharmProjects\Rough-Work\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2899, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 107, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 128, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index_class_helper.pxi", line 91, in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type
KeyError: 'name'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

(Using PyCharm on Windows 10)
 .loc method is not taking column labels! Why is it so?

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do.   
This is similar to yours.  print(df[['name', 'score']])

Comment: @NatheerAlabsi To display the two columns named 'name' and 'score' of DataFrame  df.

Comment: @NatheerAlabsi, I tried this code ; `df1 = df.loc[:,['name', 'score']]
df2 = df['name', 'score']
#print(df2.equals(df1))`
But second line is giving errors.

Comment: Look at the code you just posted, then look again, carefully, at what @NatheerAlabsi wrote.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile, I actually tried NatheerAlabsi's code and it worked. While trying to test if both ways are equal, I just posted the above comment.

Comment: @VikranthInti I’m sorry, I don’t understand what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format for .loc method is df.loc[row_slice, column_slice]

To be able to return the column labels without using loc, just use df[column_slice]

```
print(df[['name','score']])
```

Comment: another method is to declare your cols `cols = ['name','score']` then call `df[cols]`

Comment: I tried this code ; `df1 = df.loc[:,['name', 'score']]
df2 = df['name', 'score']
#print(df2.equals(df1))`
But second line is giving errors.

Comment: @VikranthInti ‘second line is giving errors.’ Please make some effort to make helping you easier. Explain things properly, include the error messages, etc. I don’t even know what that code snippet has to do with this person’s answer.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile, perhaps, the above comment should,nt be posted here. Just wanted to check the equality of both ways. kcEmenike's answer is working.

Comment: @VikranthInti The equality of both ways?

Comment: I mean `df1 = df.loc[ : , ['name', 'score']]` is not same as `df2 = df['name', 'score'] `.

Comment: Running `df.loc[ : , ['name', 'score']].equals(df[['name', 'score']])` returns `True`

Notice that the right side